# Global initialization of structure

Tags: visual-c++, struct, initialization, global-variables

How can I initialize `struct sockaddr_in` globally. Third variable `IN_ADDR sin_addr` is a nested structure.

```
struct sockaddr_in{
   short sin_family;
   unsigned short sin_port;
   IN_ADDR sin_addr;
   char sin_zero[8];
} addr;

struct in_addr {
   union {
      struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
      struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
      u_long S_addr;
   } S_un;
};
```

Comment: Are you compiling it as `C` or as `C++`?

Comment: @icepack I am working in Visual Studio 2010 and deveploing a windiws form application and compiling it as C++

Comment: That's your problem with the below answers. They all include *designated initializers* which is a `C` feature that isn't supported in `C++`. In order to use those you need to switch to `C` compilation (look for it in the project properties)

Comment: @icepack it is working for me when it is initialize in the class like  addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: @icepack I sit possible to set value of of structure globally  like addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  and so on.

Comment: Yes, once you have an object named `addr`

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1**

You cannot initalize `struct sockaddr_in` itself. You need to have a variable of this type, i.e, `addr` (as in your case) which you can initialize.

**Point 2**

You can use an inilitalizer list in brace-enclosed form to initialize the global variable. Also, you can make use of the `.identifier` option to initalize a member explicitly.

Assuming `IN_ADDR` is defined as

```
typedef struct sockaddr_in IN_ADDR;
```

you can write something like

```
struct sockaddr_in{
   short sin_family;
   unsigned short sin_port;
   IN_ADDR sin_addr;
   char sin_zero[8];
} addr = {AF_INET, 2015, .sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = 1234567890, .sin_zero = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
```

to initilialize `addr`.

Here, the `.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr` is used to denote to the particular variable to be initializeed.

Comment: I am getting following errors:1. error C2059: syntax error : '.'   2. error C2059: syntax error : '}' 3. error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '.'  4. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.' 5. error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Comment: @SaadRafey how is `IN_ADDR` defined?

Comment: @Saurav Ghosh these structure are defined winsock2.h

Comment: ...And it will fail with C++ compilation because designated initializers aren't supported

Answer (score 0):

Using your structure/union definition ... here is a sample program ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char u_char;
typedef unsigned short u_short;
typedef unsigned long u_long;

typedef struct in_addr
{
        union
        {
                struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
                struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
                u_long S_addr;
        }S_un;
}IN_ADDR;

IN_ADDR u =  // ====> Either do something like this ...
{
        .S_un.S_un_b = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
        //.S_un.S_un_w = {1, 2},
        //.S_un.S_addr = 121212
};

struct sockaddr_in
{
        short sin_family;
        unsigned short sin_port;
        IN_ADDR sin_addr;
        char sin_zero[8];
}addr = { // ==============> Or do something like this.
                10,
                20,
                .sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=12345,
                "SOCKET"
        };


int main()
{
        printf("sin_family = %d\n", addr.sin_family);
        printf("sin_port = %d\n", addr.sin_port);
        printf("sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = %ld\n", addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
        printf("sin_zero = %s\n", addr.sin_zero);


        printf("%c %c %c %c\n", u.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1, u.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2, u.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3, u.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4);
        //printf("%d %d\n", u.S_un.S_un_w.s_w1, u.S_un.S_un_w.s_w2);
        //printf("%ld\n", u.S_un.S_addr);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...And it will fail with C++ compilation because designated initializers aren't supported